# Why database collections is not creating in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried to make a connection to the database and create a new collection, it's connected successfully but collection is not showing in the MongoDB database.

Here is my connection

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gangdb")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected Successfully..");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("DB failed to connect");
  });
```

Here is my **app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const hbs = require("hbs");
const app = express();
require("./db/connection");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const Register = "./models/model";

const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const templatesPath = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/views");
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/partials");

app.use(express.static(staticPath));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", templatesPath);
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const password = req.body.password;
    const cpassword = req.body.confirmpassword;

    if (password === cpassword) {
      const registerUsers = new Register({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.email,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        age: req.body.age,
        password: password,
        confirmpassword: cpassword,
      });
      const registered = await registerUsers.save();
      res.status(201).render("index");
    } else {
      res.send("Password are not matching");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to the port: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This emits a [Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7dNu.png):

```
1 Issue:
POST http://localhost:3000/register 400 (Bad Request) register:1
```

And my Schema Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  confirmpassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Register = new mongoose.model("Register", userSchema)

module.exports = Register
```

I wanted to pass the new user's data to the database that just registered to the client side.

If my question doesn't make any sense then please I will try to provide you with anything you need.

I couldn't figure it out no matter what.
Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should import `Register` with:

```
const Register = require("./models/model");
```